# Active Admin: dedicated index page for a resource that uses belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Rails 5 (Ruby 2.5.1), activeadmin 2.2.0

I have a resource B that belongs to a resource A so I can list index views of B that belong to an instance of A.

```
ActiveAdmin.register B do
  menu false
  belongs_to :A
end

ActiveAdmin.register A do
  menu 'A'
end
```

When I try to create an index page for all instances of B independently from A, using this code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register B do
  menu false
  belongs_to :A
  actions :index 

  index do
    id_column
  end
end
```

it does not generate a dedicated index path. **When I remove** `belongs_to` **though, I get a dedicated path and the expected index view for resource B.** But I lose the functionality on resource A that come with `belongs_to`.

*How can I keep the association and have a general index page for resource B?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html#belongs-to) says that to achive this, you pass in `optional: true` to the `belongs_to` directive. So registering B would be like:

```
ActiveAdmin.register B do
  menu false
  belongs_to :A, optional: true
  actions :index 

  index do
    id_column
  end
end
```

I put together [this](https://github.com/lsizani/test-so.git) application to illustrate.

Comment: It would have been worth reading down until the very last sentence. Thanks for the hint!